# Stepper Motor turns constantly when it only should after receiving a signal from python code

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

I am writing two programs that work together to make something that spins a servo motor every set amount of seconds that can be chosen using a potentiometer. Every time either the delay gets changed or the countdown ends, the Python code sends 'T' to the arduino serial, which is then picked up by the arduino code and spins the motor, but when the stepper first starts to spin it wont stop. I also made it so that the light indicators that show the user what delay is on all flash when 'T' is picked up by the code, and they flash about every second.
Python Code:

```
import time
import serial
import threading

# Define Arduino's serial port and baud rate
arduino_port = "/dev/cu.usbserial-110"
baud_rate = 9600

# Initialize the Serial connection with the Arduino
ser = serial.Serial(arduino_port, baud_rate, timeout=1)

# Set pin numbers for LEDs and stepper motor
red_led_pin = 5
blue_led_pin = 6
green_led_pin = 7

previous_delay = 90
current_delay = 15

def func1():
    global current_delay
    global previous_delay

# Main loop
    try:
        current_delay = 0  # Initialize delay to 0

        while True:
            # Read the potentiometer value from Arduino
            ser.write(b"P\n")
            potentiometer_value = ser.readline().decode().strip()

            if potentiometer_value.isdigit():  # Check if the received data is a valid number
                potentiometer_value = int(potentiometer_value)

                if 0 <= potentiometer_value < 341:
                    current_delay = 5
              
                    #Red
                elif 341 <= potentiometer_value < 682:
                    current_delay = 10
             
                    #Blue
                else:
                    current_delay = 15
         
                    #Green
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting...")
        ser.close()


def func2():
    global previous_delay
    print(current_delay)
    print(previous_delay)
    while True:
        countdown_time = current_delay
        while countdown_time >= 0:
            if previous_delay != current_delay:
                ser.write(b"T\n")
                print("Changing Delay")
                previous_delay = current_delay
                countdown_time = current_delay
            print(countdown_time)
            countdown_time -= 1
            time.sleep(1)
            if countdown_time == 0:  
                print("Countdown finished!")
                ser.write(b"T\n")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                print("Spin Now!!!")
                print(f"Delay for stepper motor: {current_delay} seconds")
                print("-" * 30)  # Separator line

x = threading.Thread(target = func1)
y = threading.Thread(target = func2)
x.start()
y.start()
```

Arduino Code:

```
// Pins for LEDs and stepper motor
const int redPin = 5;
const int bluePin = 6;
const int greenPin = 7;
#include <Stepper.h>
const int stepsPerRevolution = 100; 
bool turn = false;

Stepper stepperMotor(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 9, 10, 11);


// Variables to store received commands
char command;


void setup() {
  // Set LED pins as output
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);


  stepperMotor.setSpeed(60); // 60 RPM


  // Initialize the serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int potValue = analogRead(A0);
    if (potValue < 341)  // Lowest third of the potentiometer's range (0-340)
  {                  
    digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
  }
  else if (potValue < 682) // Middle third of potentiometer's range (341-681)
  {

    digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(bluePin, HIGH);
  }
  else if (potValue >= 682) // Upper third of potentiometer"s range (682-1023)
  {
    digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);
  }

  // Check for incoming serial data
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // Read the command
    command = Serial.read();
    if (command == 'T');
        turn = true;
        Serial.println("Turning");
      
    // Check the received command and perform the corresponding action
    switch (command) {
      case 'P':
        // Send the potentiometer value to Python
        int potValue = analogRead(A0);
        Serial.println(potValue); // Send the value as a string followed by newline
        break;
      }
    }   
    if (turn == true){
      stepperMotor.step(stepsPerRevolution);
      digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(bluePin, HIGH);
      turn = false;
    }

    
  }
```

I tried to make it so that instead of stepping the motor directly when it recieved the signal, it instead turned on a bool which caused the motor to turn they stop it straight away (as seen in code) but this did not fix anything.

Comment: `if (command == 'T');` -- 1) You have a trailing semicolon which shouldn't be there.  2) C++ is not python -- indentation does not have any effect in C++ after that `if` block.  You have `turn = true;` and then unconditionally a `Serial.println("Turning");` which will get printed regardless.  C++ uses `{ }` to denote scope, not indentation.  Thus possibly this question should be closed as a typo.